# Generating uniformly distributed Delay in matlab with given properties

Tags: matlab

I want to generate a delay matrix in matlab with the below properties :
1. The column index of the matrix is the timestamp at which a measurement in generated. So if we have a `50X1000`  matrix each row corresponds to specific measurement `y_i(k)` where `i=1,2,\dots,50` and `k=1,2,\dots,1000`
2. The timestamp at which the measurement `y_i` will be received  = column index + value at that index. So if the value is 5 and the index is 10, the measurement `y_i(10)` is now received at `k =15`. If at the same time, we have value is 8 and the index is 7 for some `y_j, (i != j)`,  once again it is 15. In such clashes, we again generate a new delay value.
3. The minimum delay is 0 and max is 30 units in steps of 1. The overall delay distribution is discrete and almost uniform in `[0,30]`

I was able to generate delay using the above properties but it is not tending to be a uniform distribution. Please help

Comment: Please edit the question to provide runnable code for what you're trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its funny that I'm answering my own question. Using the properties of matrix cells I was able to achieve my goal. It is a code that I used in my thesis. So i can't directly share it here. will modify it and post the solution soon. Outline is that using random functions and matrix cells, we can achieve a uniformly delayed data matrix.